# PHP: Why do we use stristr() as a condition in an 'if' statement when its return type is string, not bool?

Tags: php, if-statement, strstr

The question is from a statement from a piece of code from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp) (the last PHP program on the page) The statement is:

```
if (stristr($q, substr($name,0,$len))) {...}
```

But according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php), the return type of `stristr()` is string. It returns a string, not a bool, so how can we use it in an if statement?

Comment: If `stristr()` returns any string without `''` then it is consider as `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP, like most programming languages evaluates the conditional expression (the code inside an `if` statement) to a boolean expression:

```
if (123)
    echo '123 is true';
```

This will echo the text because, when it comes to ints, everything except 0 is true (or truthy as it is also known).
You can check the official documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to get a detailed overview of what types/values evaluate to true and which to false.

Of course, in the case of `strstr` and `stristr`, when no substring is found, the function will actually return `false`, and so a type and value check of the return value is not uncommon:

```
if (stristr($string, 'needle') !== false)
    echo 'The needle was found';
```

Comment: @JuanMendes: in C, any non-zero and non-NULL value is true: `if (-1) printf("%d is true\n", -1);` works just as well

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the link to the documentation, as this confuses me quite often.

Comment: @Zarah: You're welcome. Would you mind awfully marking one of the answers as accepted, seeing as your question was answered?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I could not accept an answer in the first few minutes. It said that I can accept an answer in X minutes whenever I tried. I accepted it as soon as I could.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you posted

> Return Values
>
> Returns the matched substring. If needle is not found, returns FALSE.

When it returns a string, PHP considers non-empty strings to be truthy when used in an if statement

Comment: nit-pick, but PHP's truth tables are quite messed up: `if ("0" == false)` will evaluate to true. And worst of all `if ("php" == 0)` is true, too, just as `if ("php" == true)` is true... :-S